# Using a libgdx com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences in the Main class?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx, program-entry-point

I want to start a libgdx game using preferences saved from the options menu in the game when it is started back up. But whenever i try to instantiate a preferences file, i get a null pointer exception?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exampleGame.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Line 11 is `Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game.prefs");` i've also tried using a class that i made that does the exact same thing but just from the class.

The line would be `PreferencesLoader prefs = new PreferencesLoader();` and inside that class is `Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game.prefs");`

So how do i instantiate `Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game.prefs");` correctly so i can load preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct:

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game.prefs");
```

But you are trying to do it before the library is initialized. At least thats what I can deduce being its just the line 11 in the Main java class.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at exampleGame.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

All the Gdx.xxx will be null before the initialize is complete.

Comment: Ah you're right... I totally forgot, since the line new LwjglApplication(new exampleGame(), cfg); hasn't yet been ran.

Comment: Is there a way i can use Gdx calls in the main method before it sends run `new LwjglApplication(new examplGame(), cfg)` where cfg is the LwjglApplicationConfiguration? So i can send in info from a file?

Comment: Nop, that cannot be done. All the Gdx.xxx are created in the initialize because they are different in every platform,